# Queue up episodes in Play Movies & TV

Tags: chromecast, google-play-movies

In Google's native "Play Movies & TV", the app that plays your movie and TV content purchased from the Play Store, is there any way to queue up something to play next, or an option when watching a TV series to have it automatically play the next episode?

Maybe I've been spoiled by the Netflix app, but I was playing a TV series I had downloaded for my son on the Chromecast through a Nexus 7 tablet, and I kept having to manually select an episode to play once one was finished.  Sort of annoying since each episode was only ~10 minutes long.

I couldn't find any option for what I want but maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the YouTube app. Within the YouTube app under your account you can find purchases. Within purchases are playlists of seasons of TV shows which you can queue up to play in a row.

Netflix still does it better as it checks on you occasionally so you don't binge every episode.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know if Youtube had that integration when I was originally looking for it, but you're right, it looks like I can get at those via the YouTube app and queue them up now!

Answer (score 2):

New answer due to a new option within the Google Play movies **settings**. There is an option to **enable binge watching** which will autoplay the next episode in your library.

> App version: 3.22.14 [AU]

Comment: With this option checked, it still doesn't work. At least when using Chromecast. I'm not sure if this works when not using Chromecast.